# What are the problems if certain actions return a single partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, viewbag

I have 20 + actions which does image manipulation and return a single Image URL to a partial view as below:

```
Public async Task<PartialViewResult> action1()
{
   //Do some Image Manipulation tasks.
   //Do some API Calls and returns Json.
   //Some conditional checks.
   Viewbag.ImageURL = UrlOfTheImageObtainedFromAThirdPartyWebsite;
   return PartialView("_MyPartialView");
}
```

And continues.... The Partial View content is as here:

```
<div>
<img src="ViewBag.ImageURL" alt="the images is fetched from abc"/>
</div>
```

**The Question:** What are the pros and cons about this situation? Would it create any conflict between HTTP Requests? Is there any better alternative to this? Thank you!

Comment: other than 20 requests in quick succession, it shouldn't cause any issues. The requests won't conflict - the browser knows how to keep them separate. Your main issue is probably performance, if this action is happening 20 times on one page, especially if the requests are close together. Is there no way you can make one request to the partial and have it return all 20 (or however many) results in one hit?

Comment: Yes the whole question is about performance. No I can have them all in one call... I am doing some facebook fun tests and each action return a different image that is why? What if make 20 partials would it help?

Comment: no because you'd still need 20 requests. Partials are meant to be re-usable, anyway. If you made 20 separate partials, you might as well not bother with a partial at all. Where are you getting the variable "UrlOfTheImageObtainedFromAThirdPartyWebsite" from? It's not defined in your example.

Comment: Have a look at the following question I asked on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155463/calls-to-cloudinary-for-manipulation-or-image-upload). You'll find out how I get the images.

Comment: ok, so which requests are you concerned about? The 20 between your browser and your MVC app, or the 20 between your app and the remote service? I doubt there is much you can do about the latter. For the former, I don't know if it's possible to condense them into 1 - it depends on your UI flow and your use case.

Comment: @ADyson I worry about 20 between the server and the remote server? Is there by any chance a possibility to have these actions run in background for a user once logged in and save the result in database? I think this could be a better idea and will prevent having lots of views and partial views?

Comment: if the user doesn't need an instant response, you could definitely queue them and run as a background service, yes. It could be a separate service completely de-coupled from the UI, just sharing the database. Then the UI could just display everything has been fetched so far, based on the DB records. Perhaps you could make the UI check for updates at regular intervals, if that would improve usability.